# What happened to glDepthRange in OpenGL ES 2.0 for iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I used glDepthRange(1.0, 0.0) in a Mac OS X program to give myself a right-handed coordinate system. Apparently I don't have that option with iOS using OpenGL ES 2.0. Is there a quick fix so that higher z-values show up in front, or do I have to rework all of my math?

Comment: My understanding is that OpenGL ES 2.0 is a GL API reboot and blank slate. There is very little built-in functionality supplied, beyond fast access to the GPU. So, you'll have to roll your own. Or, some of the Apple-supplied shaders may be able to provide what you want.

Comment: Depth testing is core functionality. I can still specify much of depth testing is done, like the depth function. Perhaps there is something I am not aware of, though. Editing my shaders would qualify as "reworking my math".

Comment: sorry--that's about all I know. I'm sure you still have access to the depth buffer however... but I think it's up to your shader to decide whether to draw or not at a certain pixel. Let's hope a GL ES 2.0 expert chimes in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you can try glDepthFunc. the default value is GL_LESS, if you use GL_GREATER, pixels with higher z values will be rendered.

```
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
```

alternatively, you can add this line on your vertex shader

```
gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
```

Comment: If I use glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER) (or glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL)), then nothing shows up at all. I remember this happening in the original program and so (I think) I followed advice to use glDepthRange(). Do you know what might be happening to cause this?

Comment: * you dont see anything using glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER) because the default value of the depth is 1.0, you can change the depth's default value using glClearDepthf

Comment: Just found that out about default depth clear value and the problem with the 'f'. I edited your answer so I could accept it.